# How can I get two networks with different IP addresses In Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a router with IP addresses 192.168.0.x. (1st network).

Connected to a LAN connection is a second router with addresses 192.168.1.x. (2nd network).

**How do I make it possible for both networks to see each other?**

Comment: You can connect your PC or Device to a single network at a time. Either mobile data or wifi. If both on then in devices wifi is first priority and if LAN then LAN is first prioriy.

Comment: Yes, I can find all device's ip addresses under the same LAN. But I need All device's Ip under the same switch. is it possible?